# How to use SymPy to solve a complex equation with an approximate solution

Tags: python, sympy, solver

For example,

```
>>> integrate(sqrt(sin(u)*sin(u)+1), (u, 0, b)).subs(b, 0.22).evalf()
0.221745186045595
```

But I want to know reversedly which `b` can get 0.221745186045595. So I write

```
>>> solve(integrate(sqrt(sin(u)*sin(u)+1), (u, 0, b)) - 0.221745186045595, b)
[]
```

I know we can not get a very precise solution, so my question is: How can we set SymPy's `solve` to do that with some tolerated precision?

The function `sqrt(sin(u)*sin(u)+1)` is just an example. If possible, it should be an unpredictable, user-input function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what SymPy is for.  "Sym" in SymPy means Symbolic, as opposed to Numeric. You want numeric computations. Use SciPy `quad` and some root-finding routine like `root` or `fsolve`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate, optimize
target = 0.221745186045595
f = lambda u: np.sqrt(np.sin(u)**2 + 1)
x = optimize.root(lambda b: integrate.quad(f, 0, b)[0] - target, 0).x
```

returns `x` as `array([0.22])`.

#### Parsing user input

For turning user input into a callable function like `f` above, SymPy's [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) can be used. Example:

```
from sympy import sympify, lambdify     
f_string = "sqrt(sin(u)**2+1)"      # user input 
f_expr = sympify(f_string)
sym = next(iter(f_expr.free_symbols))
f = lambdify(sym, f_expr, "numpy")
```

Here `f_expr` is a SymPy expression parsed from a string, `sym` is the SymPy symbol (the argument of the function), and `f` is a Python function created by `lambdify`. This `f` is then used as above.

Comment: thanks. As for lambdify, I just met it can not translate `integrate` to numpy directly, for which the search gives a solution. But since I can't limit which function the user will input, so I think the better way is: after the user input the formula, I calculate f(x) on a range of number at a very small interval to get a dict, for example{0: f(0), 0.01: f(0.01), ..., 0.01*i:f(0.01*i)}. Then I find in the dic to get the `key`

Comment: I added a concrete example of how SymPy helps with turning user input into a callable function.

Comment: nice idea to express my initial integral into 2 parts. The integrand is treated by sympy's lambdify, and the integral part is done by scipy. I did not grasp this idea till @mad-physicist [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177170/find-which-parameter-gives-the-given-curve-length)